# AngularJS ngForm binding with ngIf inside ngRepeat results in undefined form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have `ngForm`-s nested within an `ngRepeat`. The forms are bound to a variable on the page's controller. Forms are then added to/removed from DOM based on the active index of a tab using `ngIf`.

Weird thing is if I activate tabs in ascending order, the form is properly bound to the controller's form variable, but if I activate tabs in the descending order, the form is not bound.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.index = 0;
  ctrl.tabs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  ctrl.text = null;

  ctrl.setIndex = function(index) {
    ctrl.index = index;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.form ? "Form is bound!" : "Form is NOT bound." }}
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.tabs">
      <ng-form name="ctrl.form" ng-if="ctrl.index===$index">
        <input type="text" ng-attr-name="{{item+'-test'}}" ng-model="ctrl.text" required/>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(0)">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(1)">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(2)">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(3)">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(4)">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why the form is unbound from controller (this must be due to `ng-repeat` internals).

However, if you bind each form to different name, i.e.:

```
<ng-form name="ctrl.form{{item}}" ng-if="ctrl.index===$index">
```

and define a simple method for accessing it:

```
ctrl.currentForm = function() {
   return ctrl['form' + ctrl.tabs[ctrl.index]];
};
```

then everything works as expected.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.index = 0;
  ctrl.tabs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  ctrl.text = null;

  ctrl.currentForm = function() {
     return ctrl['form' + ctrl.tabs[ctrl.index]];
  };
  
  ctrl.setIndex = function(index) {
    ctrl.index = index;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.currentForm() ? "Form is bound in tab with index " + ctrl.index + "!" : "Form is NOT bound." }}
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.tabs">
      <ng-form name="ctrl.form{{item}}" ng-if="ctrl.index===$index">
        <input type="text" ng-attr-name="{{item+'-test'}}" ng-model="ctrl.text" required/>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(0)">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(1)">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(2)">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(3)">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.setIndex(4)">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, eventually I ended up binding the form to a property on a ng-repeat collection item. But I'd really like to get to the bottom of this. Also if you change ng-if="ctrl.index===$index" to ng-if="ctrl.index<=$index" then it works in the reverse order